# A proper latin name for an alien creature

Tags: creature-design, aliens, names

I am designing an alien creature, an oxygen breather on an Earth-like planet. These creatures have a crest on their back that changes color according to the mood in which they are. That crest is a reminiscent of the sea creature they evolved from, a squid-like creature that changed color to camouflage and confuse predators.

I want to design a proper Latin name for them that has something to do with that crest. And I thought about "Crista coloratus". However, my Latin knowledge is limited to Google translate, and I am not sure if that really sounds like "colored crest" or another latin term should be more appropriate. The question is: **Is *Crista coloratus* a proper latin name that makes sense for these creatures?**

Comment: This question has appeared in the VTR queue. [What is the best name for X?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130#6259) questions are off-topic.  This is a minor variation ("Is this name OK?").  Questions of this type are always off-topic because it violates both SE's definition of POB [and our own](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437).  Voting to remain closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- *Crista colorat**a*** ("[crista](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dcrista)" is feminine, and scientific names generally obey basic agreement rules).
- *Versicolor cristatus*, "of changing colors with a crest".
- *X chromatolophus* (with *X* being a suitable generic name, and *chromatolophus* being Latinized pseudo-Greek for "color crested"). A whimsical choice would be *[Polytropus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Dpolu%2Ftropos) chromatolophus*, to reuse the characteristic epithet of Ulysses, which *could* be taken to mean "with many moods". (It is usually taken to mean "much experienced".) A less whimsical choice could be *Apanthropus chromatolophus*, a creature far from man and having a colored crest.
- Or, to stick with Latin, *X varicristatus* or *Varicristatus X*, "varius" meaning "of many colors"; for example, *Versimodus varicristatus*, which would mean "of changing mood with a multicolored crest".

Comment: this is excellent!

Answer (score 3):

Binomial names like Crista colorata (using AlexP's advice of agreement) will work, but do make sure that the naming makes sense.  The first word is the name of a genus, and the second word names the species within the genus.  So the first word needs to be able to stand on its own.

Genus are defined within a Family.  "Crista" needs to be a reasonable distinguishor within the family.  This is probably pretty reasonable.  An example Family is "Iguanidade," which consists of all Iguanas, or "Macropodidae," which [consists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macropodidae) of " kangaroos, wallabies, tree-kangaroos, wallaroos, pademelons, quokkas, and several others."

I think that within such a Family, "Crested" is going to be a very reasonable discriminator which can be used to define a genus, so I think your naming will work just fine, as long as any other similar crested species don't have a noticeable colored crest.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

My Latin dictionary agrees with your (Google's) translations. In addition, both elements are used in other species names.

*Hybolasius crista* is a [longhorn beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybolasius_crista) from New Zealand.

*Echis coloratus* is a [carpet viper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echis_coloratus) from the Middle East.